# Valid to / Expiration date inclusive or exclusive

Tags: validation, wording, best-practice

I have a form with a "Valid to" date field. This field represents the date in which something will expire.

Should the "Valid to" date be inclusive or exclusive?
E.g. Valid to = **04**.02.2020. Should it be valid until **03**.02.2020 23:59:59,999? Or until **04**.02.2020 23:59:59,999

Is there best practices or regulations for expiration dates wording? 
"Valid to", "Valid thru", "Valid until", "Expiration date" or something else...?

Answer (score 3):

You're correct to think that it may be misunderstood. In cases such as these, adding a little bit extra to the label can help clarify the intent.

[image: Date input with help text specifying "end of day"]

The word "through" (or the informal abbreviation "thru") hints towards being inclusive of the date entered. In addition, to address the issue of ambiguity with dates entered via input fields, I'd suggest displaying the entered date in its long form near the input. This would give you a natural place to specify the "end of day" time as well.

Answer (score 1):

"Valid to" can be interpreted both ways, but "valid through" is clearer. See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/199268/36824

When it comes to expiration *dates* (without time of day), the best (?) way to implement a validation test is to compare with the day *after* the expiration date:

`if (testDate < expirationDate + 1)`

Otherwise you would have to add "23:59:59.999" to the expiration date, which would erroneously fail timestamps a microsecond later, or when leap seconds occur.

So the user picks an *inclusive* end date to the range, but the logic in the code converts this to an *exclusive* range (well, a half-open interval, since the start date is inclusive).

Compare with expiration dates of e.g. HTTPS certificates, which have a very exact time of day. In this case, "valid through" is instead called "not after", to convey exactly what is meant.